# Submitting app to appstore

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Is hyphen allowed in app name in iTunesConnect?

For example : `abcd - efgh`

I searched in google found the link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1892/_index.html,

No where they mentioned whether hyphen(-) allowed as app name in itunes?

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed.. You can enter `A-Za-z0-9.-_` (those are the only ones I've tried). However, if you abuse it, Apple can reject the app. Example: `Foo___Bar` can get rejected. I'm not sure if they allow consecutive characters that are not A-Za-z.

It also depends on the AppStore you submit to. They allow Chinese, Japanese, etc.

You can have AppNames like: 
"StackOverflow.com", "Foo.ca", "Scotia-Bank", "Meh_Bar", "Food-Noob.ca", etc..

Note: I do not have an official citation for this. This is just from what I have submitted.